# Rotation of a div gives a black background on IE, how can I remove it?

Tags: html, css

I am using this css class to rotate a `div`. This isn't currently working, because it gives a black background on IE9. How do I remove this?

```
.arrow-left {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 70px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:-45px;
  left:-11px;
  z-index:1;
  border-right:70px solid #009da6;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=5); /*for IE8*/
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Before

[image: Before Rotation]

After

[image: After Rotation]

Comment: yup, but this didn't work too!

Comment: Here is a screeshot http://s22.postimg.org/w6wxrdoy9/black.png

Comment: a normal triangle, here is a screenshot without rotation http://s10.postimg.org/up1iqc0hl/notblack.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected this just by removing the filter line. My code is now:

```
.arrow-left {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 70px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:-45px;
  left:-11px;
  z-index:1;
  border-right:70px solid #009da6;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: This works for IE9, but it means there will be no rotation for IE8.